# movie2avi frame size error and keeping frame size constant

Tags: matlab

I'm having issues with Matlab's movie2avi function; it keeps giving the error:

```
Error using avifile/addframe>ValidateFrame (line 288)
Frame must be 266 by 343.

Error in avifile/addframe (line 158)
ValidateFrame(aviobj,width, height,dims);

Error in movie2avi (line 64)
avimov = addframe(avimov,mov);
```

Now as I understand this is caused by the frames not being of consistent size, so I guess my question is how am I supposed to define the size of the frames while keeping the axes equal?
My code as it stands is:

```
for i = 1:days+1
    plot3(npath(i,1),npath(i,2),npath(i,3),'yellow') %sun
    hold on
    plot3(npath(i,4),npath(i,5),npath(i,6),'blue') %mercury
    plot3(npath(i,7),npath(i,8),npath(i,9),'red') %venus
    plot3(npath(i,10),npath(i,11),npath(i,12),'blue') %earth
    plot3(npath(i,13),npath(i,14),npath(i,15),'red') %mars
    plot3(npath(i,16),npath(i,17),npath(i,18),'blue') %jupiter
    plot3(npath(i,19),npath(i,20),npath(i,21),'red') %saturn
    plot3(npath(i,22),npath(i,23),npath(i,24),'blue') %uranus
    plot3(npath(i,25),npath(i,26),npath(i,27),'red') %neptune
    plot3(npath(i,28),npath(i,29),npath(i,30),'blue') %pluto
    set(gca,'color','black')
    axis('equal')
    view(2)
    mov(i) = getframe();
end
hold off
movie2avi(mov,'movie.avi')
```

This is the end of my code plotting the (x,y,z)positions,npath, of the Sun, the planets and Pluto for each day in the range of the variable days.

Also I apologise if this is a stupid question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `xlim` `ylim`  `zlim` lines to fix your axis with the global min to max value of each of them.
For example, before you `getframe` write:

```
xlim([-10 10]);
ylim([-10 10]);
zlim([-10 10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that the size of the axis changes during the animation. The `getframe()` command you use is equivalent to `getframe(gca)`, therefore you get frames of different size. The problem should be fixed by using `getframe(gcf)` instead. For details on a similar problem, see [movie2avi - how to fix the frame size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949050/movie2avi-how-to-fix-the-frame-size).