# movie2avi - how to fix the frame size?

Tags: matlab, animation, ffmpeg, movie

I have searched stackoverflow for a similar question and I found question "movie2avi-frame-size-error-and-keeping-frame-size-constant".  Unfortunately the answer given there did not solve my problem (it has been suggested the use of xlim, ylim and zlim).

In what follows I send a lightly modified version of a well-known example given elsewhere.

```
%# figure
figure, set(gcf, 'Color','white')
Z = peaks; surf(Z);  axis tight
set(gca, 'nextplot','replacechildren', 'Visible','off');
[az,el]=view;
xl=xlim;
yl=ylim;
zl=zlim;

%# preallocate
nFrames = 20;
mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata',[], 'colormap',[]);

%# create movie
for k=1:nFrames
   view([(az-k*10) el]);
   xlim(xl);ylim(yl);zlim(zl);
   drawnow;pause(0.1);
   mov(k) = getframe(gca);
end
close(gcf)

%# save as AVI file, and open it using system video player
movie2avi(mov, 'myPeaks1.avi', 'compression','None', 'fps',10);
```

The idea is to rotate the figure and create a movie.  Everything works fine except for the last command, that is, movie2avi.  The error msg is

```
Error using avifile/addframe>ValidateFrame (line 290)
Frame must be 435 by 344.

Error in avifile/addframe (line 158)
ValidateFrame(aviobj,width, height,dims);

Error in movie2avi (line 67)
avimov = addframe(avimov,mov);

Error in more_video_test (line 24)
movie2avi(mov, 'myPeaks1.avi', 'compression','None', 'fps',10);
```

I have looked at approaches-to-create-a-video-in-matlab here in stackoverflow and found that:

a) Solution ffmpeg works but I would like to avoid it.
b) All other solutions failed even QTWriter.  How can I fix the frame size so that all these other solutions work?

Many thanks.

Ed

Comment: Have a look at the newer `VideoWriter` class in MATLAB.  You still use `getframe`, but then you use the `writeVideo` method to save out each frame inside the loop.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html

Comment: It's not a "nice" solution so I won't post it as an answer, but I think that if you specify a rectangle in getFrame (e.g. getframe(gca, [0 0 435 344]);) should solve this...

Comment: Also, setting the position attribute of the axis might solve this.

Comment: @chappjc - I did and the problem still persists.

Comment: @pseudoDust - Many thanks.  getframe(gca, [0 0 435 344]) did the job but the resulting avi was cropped.   Sometimes I can see I can the axes, sometimes I cannot.

Comment: @pseudoDust - Could you be so kind to elaborate a bit more on how to set the position attribute of the axes? Many thanks.

Comment: use [set](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) e.g. set(gca, 'position', [20 20 500 500])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that due to the rotation of the graph the size of the axis changes, so you end up with a sequence of frames of different sizes. You can see this if you insert the lines

```
s = size(mov(k).cdata);
fprintf('%d %d\n', s(2), s(1))
```

within the loop, directly after you grabbed the frame by

```
mov(k) = getframe(gca);
```

The result is

```
435 344
435 343
435 343
436 342
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
435 343
```

Because the first frame has the size 435 x 344, `movie2avi` expects the following frames to be of the same size – but they're not.

In order to fix this, you might want to set the axis size (& position) explicitly using `set(gca, 'Position', [...])`. An easier workaround though is to grab the frame not from the axis, but from the figure. That is, instead of `mov(k) = getframe(gca);` use

```
mov(k) = getframe(gcf);
```

The frames then have a uniform size of 560 x 420.

On my machine, the resulting avi has frames upside down. In order to fix this, too, you can additionally insert a line

```
mov(k).cdata = mov(k).cdata(end :-1: 1, :, :);
```

after grabbing the frame.

Comment: @Donda - Thank you ever so much.  I have used the workaround and change to writeVideo to get the rotation.   On a mac, I did not need to insert the extra line to avoid frames upside down.  Is that a Windows issue?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure about the bug. I'm on Linux, but I did make movies before and didn't have to flip...

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution to my question.

```
%# figure
figure, set(gcf, 'Color','white')
Z = peaks; surf(Z);  axis tight
set(gca, 'nextplot','replacechildren', 'Visible','off');
axis vis3d

% With VideoWriter

writerObj = VideoWriter('myPeaks3.avi');
open(writerObj);

%# preallocate
nFrames = 90;
mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata',[], 'colormap',[]);

%# create movie
for k=1:nFrames
   camorbit(360/nFrames,0,'data','z');
   drawnow;
   mov(k) = getframe(gcf);
   writeVideo(writerObj,mov(k));
end;

% Close file

close(writerObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I habe the same problem, the frame size is changing during making a video. After searching a long while in internet I didn't find a good solution. But when I tried adding drawnow after getframe calling and before writeVideo calling. The problem is solved and didn't appear any more.

I'm using matlab 2017b.

e.g.

```
mov(k) = getframe(gcf);
drawnow;
writeVideo(writerObj,mov(k));
```